# Xamarin: Deserializing XML - "There is an error in XML document"

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In order to use some XML files in my Xamarin-Forms project, I'm trying to recreate the steps given in this [example code](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithFiles/) , however I always get the error message:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

The example code works fine by the way.

This is the XML file I use (as an embedded resource):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Name>One</Name>
    <State>Alpha</State>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>Two</Name>
    <State>Two</State>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

This is the C# code I use:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XmlTestProject
{
    public class XmlContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        public XmlContentPage()
        {

            //get access to xml file
            var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XmlTestProject.XmlFile.xml");
            List<Item> items;
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>));
                items = (List<Item>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            var listView = new ListView();
            listView.ItemsSource = items;

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    listView
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community edition and Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.5-pre2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml should have **ArrayOfItem** instead of **Items** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfItem>
  <Item>
    <Name>One</Name>
    <State>Alpha</State>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>Two</Name>
    <State>Two</State>
  </Item>
</ArrayOfItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

try declaring a wrapper class for your list, and then deserialize like this:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemList));
ItemList items = (ItemList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

listView.ItemsSource = items.Items;

[XmlRoot("Items")]
public class ItemList
{
    public ItemList() {Items = new List<Item>();}
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("State")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```